# fetching a json every second

Tags: reactjs, json, intervals

Hello I need to implement a realtime app with reactjs.
Now I need to make the function that fetches the realtime json every second. what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch data from an API in React and update it in real-time, you can use a combination of **useEffect** and **setInterval**.

```
function ScoresApp() {
const [matchData, setMatchData] = useState(null);
const [realtimeData, setRealtimeData] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
// Fetch match data (general information) once
fetchMatchData();

// Fetch real-time data every second
const interval = setInterval(fetchRealtimeData, 1000);

// Clean up the interval on component unmount
return () => clearInterval(interval); }, []);

const fetchMatchData = async () => {
try {
  const response = await fetch('your-match-data-api-url');
  const data = await response.json();
  setMatchData(data);
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error fetching match data:', error)};
const fetchRealtimeData = async () => {
try {
  const response = await fetch('your-realtime-data-api-url');
  const data = await response.json();
  setRealtimeData(data);
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error fetching real-time data:', error);
}};
return (
<div>
  {/* Render the match data */}
  {matchData && (
    <div> <h2>Match Information</h2> </div>)}
  {realtimeData && (
    <div> <h2>Real-Time Scores</h2> </div>)}</div>)}
```